# Get TH index number using Xpath in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, html-table

Hi I just want to get the index number of TH column using *unique* *Xpath*. Like A loop will run and check on which `TH column Xpath` match and *return the index number*. Is there any way i can do this in selenium ? Till now im able to get the tag index and run the the loop but now I have check the on each TH with xpath rather its matched or not and give me the index number. Please let me know is there anything with Im able to achieve this with this logic or any other any `Xpath` techniques.

```
Table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/thead[@class='ui-datatable-thead']"))

List<WebElement> rows_head = Table.findElements(By.tagName('th'))

int head_size= rows_head.size()

System.out.println(head_size);

for (int c = 1; c <= head_size; c++) {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(
       "//th[4][@class='ui-state-default ui-unselectable-text ui-sortable-column']")
    )
    // Here is something I want loop will check the each TH with above given
    // Xapth and return the TH index in the table on match TH xpath index.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium doesn't supply an API to return the xpath of found element. So you can't archive your goal by comparing xpath.

But Selenium supply API to get the attribute value of found element, you can compare with it to see it's your desired element or not.

```
WebElement thead = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/thead[@class='ui-datatable-thead']"));

List<WebElement> heads = thead.findElements(By.tagName('th'));

int head_size= heads.size()

System.out.println(head_size);

String expectedClass = "ui-state-default ui-unselectable-text ui-sortable-column"

int i = 1;
for (; i <= head_size; i++) {

    if(heads[i].getAttribute("class").equal(expectedClass))
      // check attribute class value is as expect
      // you can change to other attribute or check more than one attribute 
      break;
    )
}

System.out.println("Matched th index: " + i);
```

Comment: Thank you yeah I have achieved this  with xapth  then get text things :)